# How to terminate Google App Engine instance programmatically in Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to prevent Google App Engine instances from continuing to run when critical initialization fails. How can I do it programmatically in Java? `System.exit()` does not work in GAE.

I want to write it in the implementation of `ServletContextListener` like below.

```
public class AppContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent context)
    {
        try
        {
            // Initialization
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            // Fatal. Terminate this Google App Engine instance.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent context)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you throw your exception (or UnavailableException) in the "catch" block?  This should stop your application from starting.  I've seen that throwing certain exceptions from a servlet marked as load-on-startup will cause this, but it's considered more proper to do this from a ServletContextListener as you have above.